# Azure Data Factory Managed Instance -> Snowflake text with escape characters

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory, azure-sql-managed-instance

I've got a Copy Data Activity in Data Factory which takes a table from a SQL Server Managed Instance and puts it into a Snowflake Instance.
The activity uses a temporary staging BLOB account.

When debugging the pipeline it's failing.
The error comes up as "Found character 't' instead of record delimiter '\r\n'".
It looks like it's caused by escape characters, but there is no options available to deal with escape characters on a temporary stage.

I think I could fix this by having two activities 1 moving Managed Instance to BLOB and 1 moving BLOB to Snowflake, but would prefer to handle it with just the 1 if possible.

I have tried to add to the user properties;

```
                    {
                        "name": "escapeQuoteEscaping",
                        "value": "true"
                    }
```

Is there anything else I could add in here?

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: `...but there is no options available to deal with escape characters on a temporary stage.` The options to deal with escape characters are on the file format. Stages don't have that option even if they're permanent. Also, the file looks as if it may be tab delimited. If that's the case, you can use `\t` as the column delimiter and `\r\n` as the row delimiter in the file format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the file format where you specify the details of the file being ingested, not the stage.

There are many options including the specification of delimiters and special characters within the data. The message

> Found character 't' instead of record delimiter

suggests that you may have a tab-delimited file, so you could set `\t` as the delimiter in the file format.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-file-format.html